# Regex Syntax in .Net

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to match a line, and replace the trailing characters and newline with a newline, parenthesis, newline...while preserving the rest of the line.
In Sed, I would do something like:

```
    /^thisline./s/$.\n/\n\)\n/
```

or? I forget, its been a while...

```
   s/^thisline./$.\n/\n\)\n/
```

In order to match:

```
    thisline: "blah etc blah",\n
```

and replace it with:

```
    thisline: "blah etc blah"\n)\n
```

I am unfamiliar with the .Net Regex methods though.  How do I implement this function in System.Text.RegularExpressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method (follow the link to see it in MSDN). You'll find the regular expression syntax pretty similar, and this page gives you sample code for it. Something like this:

```
new Regex(pattern).Replace(input, replacement);
```

I can't work out exactly from your post what your pattern should be, as I can't see how you are determining what constitutes "trailing". If you can be more explicit, I can give you more detail. But I suspect you can fill in the blanks yourself from your question.

Comment: So, a regular expression of something like `[^\n]\n` to be replaced with `\n)\n`?